# i need the icon to disappear after application is closed

Tags: vb.net, winforms

my winforms app puts a little icon in the taskbar next to the clock while it's running. how do i make it disappear when i close the program in vb.net?

after the application is closed and i put my mouse over it, it disappears.

Comment: How do you put the little icon in the taskbar? Are there methods available with that feature that perform a "remove icon from the task tray" function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NotifyIcon.Visible = False OR NotifyIcon.Dispose(True)

Answer (score 2):

If this is a NotifyIcon, then you can try calling the NotifyIcon.Dispose() in the Form.Closing event.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your application is closed ? You say the icon is next to the clock so I would guess you're not in the notification area, the place where applications in background mark they are still alive.

Anyway, you put this icon yourself (since it doesn't do that by default), so there is probably a similar function to remove yourself from the notification area.

Without your code, we can't help you much further.